# Communication between two apps in Android

Tags: android

I have a question regarding the communication between two apps in Android. Below is my question,

Let's say I'm watching a video using any mobile browser or a native android app. Firstly, Can I Use something like an snipping tool (or an alternative tool) to crop a persons face in the video (and this should not send my video running application to background)? and Secondly, Can I send the cropped image to another native android app (my own created app) running in the background?

Is this possible, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to download the video you are watching and then you can edit/crop video but while editing your video player app will go in back ground.
And yes you can definately share video with other app, for that you ca nuse MediaStore class.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html

Comment: Thanks for the info Akshay. What I precisely need to do is that when a video is running, I should be able to crop a persons face and send that cropped image to my android app running in the background.